# Follow up of normal mapping problem in GLSL

Tags: texture-painting

As a follow up to [Problem with normal map display in glsl texture paint mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21002/problem-with-normal-map-display-in-glsl-texture-paint-mode) I have attempted to analyze my model further. Please see attached images demonstrating inconsistency between 2 objects in a scene when viewed with glsl shading. Both objects have the same material applied, both are uv unwrapped with no textures applied. There is one sun lamp in the scene. As far as I can tell the only difference between the two objects is that the leg object (appended from another .blend) shows that it has a cycles property and that it does not display properly in glsl. I assume something is preventing this object from displaying properly in this scene and ultimately preventing it from displaying a normal map properly in glsl as well. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much file dissection I found the simple answer to my problem. The draw settings in the object properties for the leg model was set to solid and not texture, thereby preventing the object from displaying properly in texture viewport mode needed for glsl. Frustrating how these little innocent settings can foul things up. Thanks to the community for attempting to resolve my problem.